# MailSystem.Net is there a way to check the status (if it is read or unread) of an email?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, imap, pop3, mailsystem.net

If anyone is familiar with MailSystem.Net, can you help me?

I would like to see the status of an email that is fetched with Imap4 and Pop3. I would like to see if the fetched email has already been read or is still unread.

```
int nIndex = 10;
Header EmailMessage = inbox.Fetch.HeaderObject(nIndex);
```

I would like to know if the fetched email is read or unread. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An email server has no idea whether any human eyes were used yet.  Thank heavens.

Comment: What are you asking? How to verify that the *recipients* have seen the email sent by your code? Or to verify that the user of your application has actually read the email you downloaded? MailSystem.NET can't do something that isn't already supported by the protocols

Comment: I was simply asking if you can check to see if the email was marked seen/read or unseen/unread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Exchange server` then you can. With POP3 **no** as the message is downloaded. With IMAP you can with `MessageInfo.Flags` which has flag `Flag.Seen` property.

As comments above note, you can only detect if the email has been opened but not read.